# How to set the values to form bean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I'm getting values from jsp page(struts) and form bean has getters and setters methods.I'm making ajax call, so that time i'm not getting any session values.So i would like to add those values when setting values to bean.Please look into below code , you will understand.

```
 private SearchFilters filters;

public SearchFilters getFilters() {
    return (SearchFilters) getSession().get("Filters");
}

public void setFilters(SearchFilters filters) {
      getSession().put("Filters",filters);
}
```

SearchFilters  is class which have getters and setters for form fields.After getting session values from session and setting to for bean.Now , i need to add some of the values to bean here.

How to add those values here ?

jquery:

```
jQuery.ajax({
     type : 'GET',
     url : 'url',
     data : {"prodnbr" : $("#productsTextArea1").val()},
     dataType : 'json'
```

How to use with this ajax code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery, you can make ajax call as bellow to bind values to your SearchFilters

```
$.post('/url', {
        'filters.field1': 'value1',
        'filters.field2': 'value2'
    },     
    function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

--updated

another way for ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : '/url',
    data : {
        'filters.field1': 'value1',
        'filters.field2': 'value2'
    }
);
```